# Positioning div outside of overflow scroll without using absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, overflow

I'm making a simple blog theme and I want to have a little box displaying the post date on left off-set of each post like so: http://s21.postimg.org/fjygwqw1z/timestamp_Mockup.png

However, the post's container has an overflow-y set to scroll and attaching the timestamp div to each post won't show as it's hidden by the overflow. I can get around this if I set the timestamp div to position: absolute but then it doesn't stay in-line with the post and instead stays fixed in one place.

Here's a simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/MeVwt/

```
<style>
#leftCol{
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    float: left;
}
#rightCol{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    background: orange;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: left;
}
.content{
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    margin-left: -50px;
}
</style>

<div id="leftCol">
</div>

<div id="rightCol">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
        Fish
    </div>

</div>
```

What I'm trying to do is make the purple box (.box) show outside its container (.content) and appear in the green area without setting it to a fixed position so it still scrolls with the content.

Comment: I played around with it, but I'm not sure this is the answer you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/MeVwt/1/

Comment: I want this but I want the purple box to stay in-line with the content, in this case "Fish". I suppose I should've added another element to symbolise a post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you overlap the `#leftCol` with the `#rightCol` (by positioning them `absolute` to `left:0;` of their parent container), set the left margin to the width of the left column, then set `.content` position to `relative` and box position to `absolute`, and adjust the positioning using `left`.

Here is the updated CSS:

```
#leftCol{
    position:absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background: green;
    left:0;
}
#rightCol{
    position:absolute;
    padding-left:100px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    left:0;
}
.content{
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;
}
```

and a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MeVwt/4/)

Hope this helps =)

Answer (score 1):

You could just create another div around the actual content and then float it next to the box.
Like this http://jsfiddle.net/MeVwt/3/
Downside with this is that you have to specify the width of the content for it to fill out all the width.

```
<div id="rightCol">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="content_text">
            Fish
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.content_text{
    height: 700px;
    background: red;
    width: 335px;
    float:left;
}
.box{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: purple;
    margin-left: -50px;
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

html {
 overflow-x: hidden;        }

body {
 overflow-x: hidden;       }